# How to test a recipe with template?

Tags: chef-infra

I would like to test my recipe which includes a template. 
chef-apply command does not work with a template (as per [bug report](https://tickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-4002))
I have 11.12.4 version.

How can I test a recipe with template?

Comment: What do you mean by "test"?

Answer (score 0):

I think the 'approved' method of testing chef recipes, including templates, is via test kitchen: http://kitchen.ci. You can do interactive verification or use something like minitest or bats to automate the verification of the pieces you're looking to examine.